# Is this equation with integrals true? If it is, how?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

This equation is from the physics book. It says we rearrange integrals in left part and get the right part, but I don't understand how it is done.
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt \left ( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega'C\left ( \omega' \right ) e^{-i \omega' t} \right ) e^{i \omega t} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega'C\left ( \omega' \right )\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt e^{i\left ( \omega - \omega' \right ) t}
$$

Comment: It is clear that: $$C(\omega')e^{-i\omega't}e^{i\omega t}=C(\omega')e^{i(\omega-\omega')t}$$ Now you need to show that the order of integration is interchangeable

Comment: In physics, one will not be too concerned about the change of order of integration. In LHS, one integrate $\omega'$ first, followed by $t$. In RHS, one integrate $t$ first, followed by $\omega'$. In the intergrand, the only $t$ dependent piece is $e^{i(\omega-\omega')t}$, Since $C(\omega')$ is independent of $t$, one move it outside the $t$-integral.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a change in order of integration, from first going from $\omega'$ to $t,$ in reverse order. And your domain is a rectangle, albeit an infinite one.

Answer (score 0):

This change of the order of integration operators is analogous to $\sum_i\sum_ja_{ij}=\sum_j\sum_ia_{ij}$. Conditions sufficient for this change to be legal are given in [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).